# OpenGL geometry performance

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I have an application which renders many filled polygons with OpenGL, in 2D. Filling is done by tesselation but performance is not optimal. 1900 polygons made up of 122000 vertex (that is, about 64 vertex per polygon) are displayed in about 3 seconds.

Apparently, the CPU is not the bottleneck, as if I replace calls to gluTessVertex by calls to glColor - just to test where is the bottleneck, performance is doubled.
I have the same problem with loading many small textures.
Now, which are the options to improve the performance? Seems that most time is spend in the geometry subsystem. Rendering is fast enough.

I already have a worker thread which does the load (so tesselation, texture binding) in one context, and another thread which does the draw in another context. The two contexts share objects via wglShareLists and it works like a charm.
Can I have a third thread in a third context which would handle also tesselation for half of the polygons? Anyone tried that? Is it safe? Any example of sharing objects between three contexts?

Forgot to say, I have an ATI Radeon HD 4550 graphics card, suppose it can handle more than 39kB/s of data.

Comment: why you using tessellation for 2D?

Comment: The bottleneck is lack of asynchronicity. Worker threads with shared contexts make the issue worse, not better (more sync points). See the answer by Vallentin for what you have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Increase Performance

Sounds like you're using the old fixed-function pipeline.

If you're unsure of what that is, well, the following functions are a part of the fixed-function pipeline.

- `glBegin()`
- `glEnd()`
- `glVertex*()`
- `glTexCoord*()`
- `glNormal*()`
- `glColor*()`
- etc.

Those functions are old and render geometry immediately. That means that each time you call the above functions, that geometry gets send to the GPU. By doing that a lot of times, you can easy make the FPS go way under 60 just by rendering simple things.

Now you need to use buffers and to be more precise [VAOs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Array_Objects#Vertex_Array_Object) with/or [VBOs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) (and IBOs).

VBO or Vertex Buffer Object, is a buffer which can store vertices which you then can render. This is much much faster and better to use than `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. When you create a VBO you supply it with vertices and they only require to be send to the GPU once, that's basically why they are fast, because they already are in the GPU and only require a single draw call instead of multiple.

*The reason I said "with/or" is because in the newer versions you need to create a VAO which then would use a VBO, where before you could simply render the VBOs.*

---

### Tessellation

There are multiple ways to do tessellation and things which look like/would give the effect of tessellation.

For instance you could also simply render different models according to the required [LOD (Level of Detail)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail), thereby when you're up close to an object you then render the model with all it's details which probably would have a high vertices count. Then the further you're away from the model you simply render another version of that model but which have less vertices, which also equals less detail. **Though** if you can't really do that on something like terrain and definitely shouldn't do it on something like dynamic terrain and/or procedurally generated terrain.

You can also do actual geometry tessellation and you would do that through a [Shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader). Since tessellation is a really huge topic I will provide you with 2 urls which both explain and have code on them.

*Both of these articles uses modern 4.0/4.0+ OpenGL.*

1. http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48
2. http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/tessellation.html

---

### Texturing

Generating and binding textures are still the same.

Instead of using `gluBuild2DMipmaps()` you can use `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` it was added in OpenGL version 3.0'ish if I remember correctly.

Again you can (and should) change all you `glBegin()` - `glEnd()` (and everything in between) calls out with VAOs and VBOs. You can store *everything* you want inside a buffer vertices, texture coordinates, normals, colors, etc. You can store the things in separate buffers or you can store them inside a single buffer, usually called an *Interleaved Buffer* or *Interleaved VBO*.

You wouldn't be needing `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` anymore, because you do that within a Shader, you bind textures and use them in a Shader, and since you create the Shader Program you can make it act however you want it to.

Comment: I understand the point, but is there an alternative to GLUtesselator using VBOs? My polygons may be concave.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. How about texture loading? Is there an alternative to     `glGenTextures(1, &mIndex);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mIndex);
 gluBuild2DMipmaps(...)`
 then when drawing:
 `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mIndex);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); 
  glVertex3d(x,y,z);
  ....
 glEnd();
 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

Comment: @user3004069 Look at edited answer, though you shouldn't add more stuff to your question instead you should write a new question unless it is relevant to your main question. But since you're new I answered on your comment anyways! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I close the question